# Mutating an upvar captured by value in a FnMut closure

Tags: closures, rust

I am attempting to create a simple program, with a closure containing a collection that progressively empties itself:

```
fn main() {
    let vector = vec![1, 2, 3];

    let mut allow_once = move |i: &i32| -> bool {
        if let Some(index) = vector.position_elem(i) {
            vector.remove(index);
            return true
        }
        false
    };

    for e in &[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3] {
        let is_in = if allow_once(e) { "is" } else { "is not" };
        println!("{} {} allowed", e, is_in);
    }
}
```

It seems kosher (to me), but rustc complains (on nightly):

```
<anon>:6:13: 6:19 error: cannot borrow captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure as mutable
<anon>:6             vector.remove(index);
                     ^~~~~~
```

I expect that the issue might be one of desugaring. That is, while the implementation never violates the Aliasing XOR Mutation principle, maybe the desguaring is so that `rustc` does not realize it.

Thus:

1. Is this a temporary limitation/bug or is it intrinsic?
2. How can I create a closure with a mutable environment, as efficiently as possible?

Note: Capture by reference is not an option, I wish to be able to move the closure around.

Comment: Convention is `vec![1, 2, 3]` over `vec!(1, 2, 3)`, incidentally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem can be solved easily, in fact. Just add `mut` qualifier to `vector`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut vector = vec![1, 2, 3];

    let mut allow_once = move |i: &i32| -> bool {
        if let Some(index) = vector.position_elem(i) {
            vector.remove(index);
            true
        } else { false }
    };

    for e in &[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3] {
        let is_in = if allow_once(e) { "is" } else { "is not" };
        println!("{} {} allowed", e, is_in);
    }
}
```

(working code [here](http://is.gd/cRpOIg))

It's just the same mutability rules as always - in order to mutate something, it has to have `mut` somewhere, either in its variable declaration or in its type (`&mut`).

Comment: Doh! I thought that declaring `allow_once` `mut` was sufficient (inherited mutability) and tried about everything short of that...

Comment: Yeah, on one hand it may appear confusing, but on the other hand there is no explicit move between variables, so `mut` rules still take effect. For example, if this was an `FnOnce` closure you could move the variable like `let mut vector = vector` and then `mut` qualifier on the original variable wouldn't matter.

Comment: I want to print the length of vector at the end of `main()`, if I add `println!("{}", vector.len());`, the compiler actually says, `cannot move out of \`vector\` because it is borrowed rustc(E0505)`